# stereochem of epoxide opening

Tags: stereochemistry

Here I have an epoxide opening reaction, but I was wondering that when a nucleophile attacks, How would the stereochemistry work? I have 2 products I predicted and I'm not sure which one would be correct. It's either the first one predicted in the reaction of the second picture I have attached. Or are they actually the same thing?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Where did you get the second one from?

Comment: @orthocresol It's just another prediction I had, so I wasn't sure which one is right

Comment: Yes, and why did you predict that? For example in your first one, you have a (very good!) mechanism which explains why you’re coming up with that particular stereochemistry.

Comment: @orthocresol I predicted that because I thought that with inversion, the bond would get flipped to the other side. So when you have a SN2 would only the dash and the wedge exchange if the leaving group is on the dash/wedge?

Comment: Hmm, yes, you could put it that way. If you're not fully convinced, my suggestion would be to make a model of it. That's the ultimate source of truth.

Comment: A few points to ponder. The stereochemistry of the epoxide implies a single enantiomer. If the reaction is indeed SN2, then there is inversion of stereochemistry. If you know how to assign R/S configurations, compare your two bromohydrin structures. Are they the same? What if the reaction is SN1? Lastly, what is the significance of the bold wedge in the bromohydrins?

Answer (score -1):

In these three-membered ring reactions, it's an SN2 substitution reaction that happens. Hence, there is an inversion of the configuration associated.

**Edit:** Perhaps the mechanism is more complicated than SN2, contrary to Klein's book which states that it's SN2, [this online source](https://www.brainyresort.com/en/bromonium-reactivity/) says that the actual mechanism is between sn1 and SN2 (leaning to SN2 side) to explain the preference of nucleophile to attack tertiary carbon though more sterically hindered.

---

**Reference:** See page-431 of Organic Chemistry David-R-Klein

Comment: Well, it could have some SN1, given the relative stability of a benzylic cation. I think that is what user55119's comment hints at. I'm not sure about the relative extents.

Comment: @orthocresol: I was not pushing for an SN1 mechanism but rather for the OP to ponder the consequences of an SN1 mechanism vs. an SN2 route.

Comment: Why the down vote? If there is any mistake in my answer I'd be more than happy to correct it.